# bootstrap and codeIgniter data display in table

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, foreach, html-table, codeigniter-3

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <?php foreach ($pin_data as $pin) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $pin->location;?> <?php  echo $pin->pincode;?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    } ?>

  </table>
```

Im fetching data from database.I wanted to display that data in table, but i wanted to display 5 column in a row. after that it start with new row. plz help.

Comment: read again my q.

Answer (score 0):

you add < tr> in first value and you add "< /tr>" in fifth value. it will run.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<?php $timer=1;
 foreach ($pin_data as $pin) {
 if($timer%5==1)
 {
 ?>
  <tr>
 <?php
 }
  ?>
    <td><?php  echo $pin->location;?> <?php  echo $pin->pincode;?></td>
  if($timer%5==0)
  {
  ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
   }
  <?php
   $timer++;
   } ?>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Do something like this :*

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <?php foreach ($pin_data as $pin) { ?>
      <tr>

         /*change your column name as according to you*/

         <td><?php  echo $pin->location;?></td> 
         <td><?php  echo $pin->pincode;?></td>
         <td><?php  echo $pin->location;?></td> 
         <td><?php  echo $pin->pincode;?></td>
         <td><?php  echo $pin->location;?></td> 
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator and a counter:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <tr> <!-- start initial row -->
    <? $counter = 1; 
       foreach ($pin_data as $pin):?>
          <td>
              <?= $pin->location;?> <?= $pin->pincode;?>
          </td>
       <?if($counter % 5 == 0):?> //if $counter is a multiple of 5, close the current row and start an new one 
       </tr> 
       <tr>  
       <?endif;?>
       <? $counter++;?>
       <?endforeach;?>
</table>
```